# Is there a way to quickly save helpful answers for users who are too low-rep to vote?

Tags: support, reputation, bookmarks, recent-activity

I spend considerable time finding helpful answers here on SE and wish I could somehow save helpful answers for later review. Upvoting and then reviewing my activity log would do the trick, but alas I'm too low-rep to vote.

Does anybody have a way for new users to save helpful answers *within* the confines of Stack Exchange?

Comment: You can't favorite answers but you can favorite the questions they're on. Would that work? It's the star under the down arrow.

Comment: You can always use a bookmark, like with any other website you find that is of interest.

Answer (score 5):

Add the question to favourites. There's no mechanism for favoriting answers but close enough.

Comment: Great thanks! This will do until I get to voting age.

Comment: Rather than say thanks in a comment that may be deleted at anytime I think you should click the green check mark to accept the answer and reward the answerer of your question.